# Open source POP3 mail server

Tags: vb.net, pop3, mail-server

Does anyone know of any know of any open source VB.Net POP3 mail server? I have found several in VB and some in C#, but none in VB.Net so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit), it should be fairly trivial to implement a POP3 server in VB.NET.

The hardest part of writing a POP3 server is parsing the messages (and/or message spool if you end up using an mbox formatted spool), but MimeKit will handle all of that for you.

The rest is just a simple loop of reading a line of text from a network socket and parsing it as a simple command string, then sending the response.